# Matrix.RotateAt in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, matrix

I've been trying to create a rotation matrix around a specified center in **Unity3d**, but the **Matrix4x4** class doesn't provide any functions that allows me to do so, even though C# does provide a function called:

**public void RotateAt(double angle, double centerX, double centerY);**

Which is located in **System.Windows.Media** namespace but **inaccessible in Unity3d**, is there any way I can create the same rotation matrix in Unity3d? Thank you.

Comment: Even if you get access to "System.Windows.Media" Unity's Matrix4x4 won't be compatible with it. If i were you i would write extension method to Matrix4x4 which can do that and read a little bit about affine transformations.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, but when it comes to math, I am not the best at it.There must be something that I could do about this, surely. Right now I am just using a bunch of offsets to achieve a inaccurate rotation matrix which is not a great solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a rotation matrix around a point can be done following these steps:

- Tranlate that matrix to the point where you want it to rotate around.
- Rotate the matrix.
- Translate the matrix back to the origin.

This roughly translates to:

```
// Set the following variables according to your setup
Vector3 centerOfRotation = ...;
float angleOfRotation = ...;
Vector3 rotationAxis = ...;

// This should calculate the resulting matrix, as described in the answer
Matrix4x4 translationToCenterPoint = Matrix4x4.Translate(centerOfRotation);
Matrix4x4 rotation = Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleOfRotation, rotationAxis));
Matrix4x4 translationBackToOrigin = Matrix4x4.Translate(-centerOfRotation);

Matrix4x4 resultMatrix = translationToCenterPoint * rotation * translationBackToOrigin;
```

Comment: Isn't the same equation without identity matrix sufficient?

Comment: @Wuszt It is! Thank you for noticing.